# Fill the left 1/3 of the title page with color?

Tags: color, positioning, titles

This is my first time to try and write documentation by using LaTeX. The generated PDF is quite impressive, but there is one thing I have no idea of how to do it:

I would like to have the left 1/3 of my title page (created by `titlepage`) filled with color (no left and top, bottom margin), and then put the title text on it. The title will be centered, so its left part could overlap with the colored left 1/3 of the page.

Is it doable? What is the best way? Can the `picture` environment do this?

(The documentclass is `[a4paper]{report}`.)

Comment: See also [Setting background colour for part of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/setting-background-colour-for-part-of-a-page).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple solution, without complex drawing packages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{blue!20}\rule{.33\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
Title
\end{titlepage}

bar
\newpage

blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: thanks for your suggestion. I updated my solution.

Comment: Thank you.I used your way because it does not need extra package ;)

Comment: Note, however, that this requires a fairly recent (mid-2010?) version of the eso-pic package. Earlier versions did not have `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*`.

Comment: does this only work in a `titlepage` scope?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `TikZ` for this (although I'm almost certain that if all you need is a coloured rectangle, someone else will come up with a solution that does not require a full-fledged graphics package).

The `TikZ` command needs to be supplied to the `\title{}` entry to make sure it gets drawn with the title page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw [fill,red!20] (current page.north west) rectangle +(0.33\paperwidth,-\paperheight);%
Rather Long Document Title to Show that the Colour is Behind the Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: Title Page, one third red, with TikZ]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! Too bad that the tetex @ cygwin I am using doesn't come with this package,but it is still a elegant way to address my problem.Thank you!

Comment: @murphytalk if at all possible you should switch from tetex to a newer distribution like [TeXlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/)