# Textpos not showing anything

Tags: beamer, positioning, textpos

I'm trying to create a business card in LaTeX. Accordingly, I want to use `textpos` to absolutely position the various elements.

**For some reason, textpos is just not showing anything.** What I want is for it to show things, where I put them. Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Before anyone asks, yes, the `\includegraphics` command works just fine outside of the `textpos` block. There is no difference in `textpos` behaviour whether or not I have the M -- that is just to sanity check that the margins are as expected (i.e. none)

I'm using MikTeX on Windows.

My LaTeX is below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes,verbose]{textpos}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=90mm, paperheight=45mm, layoutwidth=90mm, layoutheight=45mm, left=0mm, top=0mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\usetheme{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\begin{document}
%\fontspec[Ligatures=Rare,Contextuals=Swash,Contextuals=Alternate,StylisticSet=1,Style=TitlingCaps,Style=Alternate,Style=Swash,Contextuals=Swash]{Breathe Pro}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\fontspec{Palatino Linotype}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
M

\begin{textblock*}{49mm}(10mm,10mm)\includegraphics[width=49mm]{tustinlogo01.png}\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look on [this business card question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/setting-background-colour-for-part-of-a-page/12322#12322) which has some examples, e.g. using TikZ.

Comment: Since this isn't really a question about the beamer class would you mind removing the beamer tag?

Comment: Well, it turns out that beamer is kind of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently `textpos` does not play well with `beamer` (see page 8 of the `textpos` documentation). Given what you are doing, it seems unlikely that the particular document class matters: with something like `article`, this seems to work as expected.

Comment: I guess this is the better option in the circumstances. Interestingly, the layout changed when I switched to article.

Comment: @Marcin: The main function of a class is to set the layout. You might also try the Koma Script version of `article`: `scrartcl`, which might be closer to the `beamer` style.

Comment: I note that textpos gives unexpected results if using \pagebreak. \newpage is needed instead.

Comment: @Marcin: can you give an example of that (I'm the `textpos` author)? The two macros _should_ do just about the same, but there's subtleties to both of them which could conceivably make them inequivalent, and which I'd be curious to investigate (and of course fix, if possible).

Comment: @NormanGray Bear in mind you are replying to a comment from four years ago. I don't even have the computer this was on, let alone know the versions involved. If it's not happening for you, it's probably fine.

Comment: @Marcin Ooops, so I am - sorry!

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the `overlay` option for textpos:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes,verbose,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=90mm, paperheight=45mm, layoutwidth=90mm, layoutheight=45mm, left=0mm, top=0mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\usetheme{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\begin{document}
%\fontspec[Ligatures=Rare,Contextuals=Swash,Contextuals=Alternate,StylisticSet=1,Style=TitlingCaps,Style=Alternate,Style=Swash,Contextuals=Swash]{Breathe Pro}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\fontspec{Palatino Linotype}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont
M

\begin{textblock*}{49mm}(10mm,10mm)\includegraphics[width=49mm]{tustinlogo01.png}\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

See the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) manual (p. 20):

> `beamer` automatically installs a white
>   background behind everything, unless
>   you install a different background
>   template. Because of this, you must
>   use the `overlay` option when using
>   `textpos`, so that it will place boxes
>   in front of everything. Alternatively,
>   you can install an empty background
>   template, but this may result in an
>   incorrect display in certain
>   situtations with older versions of the
>   Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Thanks, this works. HOWEVER, I would love to know why this is the case.

Comment: @Marcin See my edited answer