# Absolute positioning in beamer when using `show notes on second screen`: text on wrong page

Tags: beamer, textpos

If you compile the example below, you have a [very comfortable way to put sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48485/17127) on the slides for for LaTeX `beamer`.

However, if you uncomment the line with the option `show notes on second screen`,
then the text is set on the wrong page, namely the previous page.

Here is a(n) (almost) minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
% the following line, if not commented, moves the ``source'' to the previous page
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% ----------
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48485/17127
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}

\setbeamercolor{framesource}{fg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{framesource}{size=\tiny}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\begin{textblock*}{8cm}(4.7cm,8.6cm)
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=0.5cm,right]{framesource}
      \usebeamerfont{framesource}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesource} Source: {#1}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
   \end{textblock*}
}
% ----------

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
  \note{my note}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{title}
  a diagram
  \source{some article or url}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17987/textpos-not-showing-anything) did not really help me.

Update:

[This answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/title-picture-misplaced-in-beamer-when-using-show-notes-on-second-screen-and-a) might contain the answer.

Is this correct? Are there a better solutions to the problem? Or are there alternatives for the `\source`-command?

Can the above `\source`-command be extended to support multiple sources?

Footnotes are an easy substitute, but they are more obtrusive than the above `\source`-command. Could this easily be changed and how?

**Solution:**

The accepted answer provides the desired `\source`-command. It is convenient to use, provides a correct and unobtrusive placement, and works with `show notes on second screen`. It even supports multiple sources.

Comment: This seems related to the use of the `absolute` option to the `textpos` package in combination with the use of `pgfpages` (which is internally used by `beamer` when you enable the option `show notes on second screen`), and this type of problem has come up repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Notes on `textpos` and `pgfpages`

When `pgfpages` is active, note that any `textblock`s positioned through use of the `textpos` package with the `absolute` option will most likely be incorrectly positioned, as witnessed here. I haven't entirely worked out what the positioning behaviour is though...

Also, you should be aware of other warnings that `textpos` emits in your MWE, even though they don't appear to influence the output in this case (these warnings can be avoided by ensuring there is a paragraph break immediately before the `textblock` environments):

> ```
> Package textpos Warning: environment textblock* not in vertical mode.
> (textpos)                Environment textblock* should not have any text
> (textpos)                or printable material appearing before it.
> (textpos)                Alignment may work out wrongly.
> ```

I therefore present a solution that doesn't rely on using `textpos`, and therefore has other advantages. Alternative options include use of `textpos` but only using relative positioning; in this case, one should ensure that all `textblock`s have their origins at fixed locations in the slide (else they may move as the slide content changes), and this is harder.

### Solution avoiding `textpos`

My idea is to use the footnote facilities instead (one can still keep the original formatting and it should interact well with multiple `\source`s and real footnotes). I have shrunk the height of the `beamercolorbox` used by `\source` and the distance between the footnotes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeamercolor{framesource}{fg=gray}
\setbeamerfont{framesource}{size=\tiny}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\define@key{beamerfootnote}{nonumber}[true]{\edef\beamer@footarg{0}\def\@makefnmark{}}% have to set a number in \beamer@footarg, then it won't be automatically generated one. setting \@makefnmark to be empty means the number isn't printed. but only use this in a group else it affects following footnotes!
% instead of 'nonumber', could just use 0 as an optional argument to \footnote, but OP reports that keyval complains about this in some situations
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89539
\newcommand{\source}[1]{{\footnote[nonumber]{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[right,wd=\dimexpr\hsize-1.8em\relax]{framesource}
      \usebeamerfont{framesource}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesource} Source: {#1}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}}}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0cm}%\footnotesep is the space between footnotes (generated with a \rule)
\makeatother

% inspired by [beamer: footnote text collides with navigation symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5855)
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}%
    \hspace*{0.1cm}\par\vskip 2pt}{}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
  a diagram
  \footnote{a real footnote}%
  \footnote{a real footnote}%
  \source{some article or url}%
  \source{some article or url}%
  \footnote{a real footnote}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: illustration of output]

Note that the magic number `1.8em` that needs to be removed from the width of the `beamercolorbox` (to avoid overfull `\hbox`es) is defined in the default `beamer` template for `footnote`, and this is the space reserved for the footnote number:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footnote}{default}
{
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

### Other notes about `pgfpages`

Note that other considerations also apply when using `pgfpages` (even if indirectly), such as page numbers etc. The main advice is to fully compile the document without `pgfpages` active, then activate it and compile again with `\nofiles` invoked also.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! Not in the MWE, but in my document, this generates "Package xkeyval Error: '0' undefined in families 'beamerfootnote'.", do not yet know why. (The possibility for several sources is good, but their space is fixed at a rather large value, which is too small for two (or even three) line sources. Not dramatic.)

Comment: @Thomas: I am not sure why you get that error either, I have edited the code to use a different approach that *might* avoid it, and have also reduced the spacing between the sources as requested.

Comment: Thanks again! No error left. Looks good, more tests tomorrow. (Note: using this version of source within a caption of a figure causes a missing-number-treated-as-zero-error.)

Comment: @Thomas: I have been unable to reproduce the error you describe when using `\source` inside a figure `\caption`. Perhaps you are loading some other packages that interfere with `beamer`'s floats, or otherwise referring to the captions somewhere, eg in a list of figures?

Comment: The error apparantly appears when using `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,labelsep=none}`. Is it possible to achieve suppress the "Figure :" with beamer commands?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, `\addtobeamertemplate{caption}{\let\insertcaptionname\relax\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{}}{}`.

Comment: I accepted the answer yesterday. It does exactly what I want. Even several sources can be given an the spacing is good. Thanks again and thank you for adding further explanations! However, I still get `overfull hbox`'es.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for letting me know about the `overfull hbox` issues. I have (hopefully) fixed these now, at least for the default `footnote` template in `beamer`, which is the only version of the template I can see defined in the `beamer` sources (using `grep`).

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry, I didn't intend you to add that to your document, I was just pointing out how the template is defined initially by `beamer` to explain where I got the `1.8em` correction factor from.

Comment: Thank you again, I like documents without warnings. The quoted code for `\defbeamertemplate*{footnote}{default}` explains, why `wd=\dimexpr\hsize-1.8em\relax` was added to the `beamercolorbox`.