# How to make shaded pages and still see memoir's trim frame?

Tags: memoir, shading

I am using memoir and I have the showtrims setting activated which I want visible on my pages. I am trying to toggle shading of entire pages and so far I am not having any great success. I have looked around but not seen anything obvious that can help me but this is what I have managed to come up with:

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\stockaiv
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\trimFrame

\pagesmallroyalvo

\setbinding{4mm}
\settypeblocksize{*}{24.5pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{6pc}{7pc}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6pt}{6pc}{12pt}
\strictpagecheck
\setlength{\topskip}{1.6\topskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtStockUpperLeft{
    \colorbox{cyan}{\vspace* \stockheight \hspace \stockwidth}
  }
}

\lipsum[1-4]

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtStockUpperLeft{
  }
}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-4]


\end{document}
```

However there are two problems.

1. I can't seem to manage to fill out the page in the vertical direction. Only in te horizontal.
2. I don't seem to be able to turn it off by changing the ship out picture again.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Related question: [setting background colour for part of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/setting-background-colour-for-part-of-a-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [how to change the background color only for the current page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page)

Comment: EDIT: I added a little line to the beginning clarifying about the trim marks which are in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; the `\NoBgThispage` commands allows you to suppress the color for the pages in which the command is used:

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen,background}

\stockaiv
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\trimFrame

\pagesmallroyalvo

\setbinding{4mm}
\settypeblocksize{*}{24.5pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{6pc}{7pc}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6pt}{6pc}{12pt}
\strictpagecheck
\setlength{\topskip}{1.6\topskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgVshift{10pc}
\SetBgColor{cyan}

\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\SetBgHshift{8pc-1.5pt}}{\SetBgHshift{5pc-3pt}}
  \SetBgContents{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}%
  \bg@material
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage\NoBgThispage
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Compile the document twice.

Using the above code, only the actual page will receive a colored background; increasing the width and height of the rule, you can obtain some bleed. Here's the result obtained by replacing `\SetBgContents{\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}` with `\SetBgContents{\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth+3cm\relax}{\dimexpr\paperheight+3cm\re‌​lax}}` in the code above:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't know about the `background` package until reading your solution -- very nice!!

Comment: This solution only colors the actual page but I need a bleed. One can not trust the printing process to cut the paper perfect.

Comment: @jonalv Simply increase the width and height of the rule used to place the background, using something like `\SetBgContents{\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth+2cm\relax}{\dimexpr\paperheight+2cm\relax}}`.

Comment: Very nice, now I just need to figure out how to put this code in an environment so I can do it where I need it and not only for odd pages...

Comment: @jonalv: my code, as it is, will place the color in every page, except for those in which you explicitly use `\NoBgThispage`.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Yea, I was a bit clumsy. What I meant to say is that I want to use this for perhaps 20 pages out of a 500 pages book. I can't write `\NoBgThispage` on 480 pages and even if I could I have no way of knowing where they start. I want to turn the color on and off so that I have some control, not specify it for each page...

Comment: @jonalv you can load the package with the `some` option: `\usepackage[some]{background}` and then you can use `\BgThispage` in the 20 pages that must receive color.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1876/discussion-between-jonalv-and-gonzalo-medina)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\pagecolor` to specify the background color of the page, and `\afterpage` from [the `afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to reset to `\nopagecolor`  after the current page is output.

[image]

### Known Issues:

- As noted by @jonalv this solution places itself on top of the frame showing the paper size, so is not a good solution when you require both the frame and page color.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!20}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
\lipsum[1-11]
\pagecolor{blue!20}\afterpage{\pagecolor{red!20}}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution places itself on top of the memoir frame showing the cut paper size. That is not very good...

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `colorbox` to a `\rule` and anchored it at the bottom left, instead of the top left.

To clear it from subsequent pages, I used `\ClearShipoutPictureBG`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\stockaiv
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\trimFrame

\pagesmallroyalvo

\setbinding{4mm}
\settypeblocksize{*}{24.5pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{6pc}{7pc}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6pt}{6pc}{12pt}
\strictpagecheck
\setlength{\topskip}{1.6\topskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  %\AtStockUpperLeft{
  %  \colorbox{cyan}{\vspace* \stockheight \hspace \stockwidth}
  %}
  \AtTextLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the text area
  \color{cyan}\rule{\textwidth}{\LenToUnit\textheight}%
  }%
}

\lipsum[1-4]


\newpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\ClearShipoutPictureBG{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With some easy enough modifications (move the color to the stock end and change it to stock size) this solution can be made to cover the entire page so I get the needed bleed. However sadly enough it still covers the memoir page cutting frame. :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on cmhughes answer I came up with this solution which has all the signs of an ugly hack:

```
\documentclass[showtrims, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{transparent}

\stockaiv
\settrims{20mm}{20mm}
\trimFrame

\pagesmallroyalvo

\setbinding{4mm}
\settypeblocksize{*}{24.5pc}{1.618}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5}
\setulmarginsandblock{6pc}{7pc}{*}
\setmarginnotes{6pt}{6pc}{12pt}
\strictpagecheck
\setlength{\topskip}{1.6\topskip}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  %\AtStockUpperLeft{
  %  \colorbox{cyan}{\vspace* \stockheight \hspace \stockwidth}
  %}
  \AtStockLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the text area
  \color{cyan}\transparent{0.5}\rule{\stockwidth}{\LenToUnit\stockheight}%
  }%
}

\lipsum[1-4]


\newpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\ClearShipoutPictureBG{}


\end{document}
```

This solution has the disadvantage that the actual color needs to be calculated by taking the transparency into account so it's not the ideal solution...

[image]