# Two-color background

Tags: color

I am creating a poster using Latex and would like to split the background into two parts. Then I was wondering how we can create a background that is two-colored. For example, upper part is red and lower part is yellow (as on the exemplary image)?

[image]

Comment: Check out the related to the right, and also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header/276453#276453.

Answer (score 4):

You could use **background**. You don't give a minimal example, so your kilometres may well vary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[placement=bottom,scale=1,opacity=1]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill [red] (current page.north west) rectangle ($(current page.north east)!.2!(current page.south east)$) coordinate (a);
      \fill [yellow] (current page.south west) rectangle (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: red-yellow background]

Comment: This example gives me `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.` no matter how many times I compile it, whether with `luatex`, `pdftex`, or `xetex`.  The PDF looks OK though.

Comment: @Thérèse That's odd. It does me, too. But I have no idea why. (And I am not sure whether it did when I first wrote this answer or not. Probably I failed to notice.)

Comment: @Thérèse I'm clueless. Hence http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285813/how-can-i-avoid-a-persistent-warning-concerning-possibly-changed-labels-when-usi. Hopefully I can correct this answer when I learn how. If you think I should delete it for now, let me know. I'm reluctant to do that since it does seem to produce the desired output, there are no other answers and it is a warning rather than an error. (I don't mean warnings don't matter - just that if it gave an error, I would definitely delete it, whereas a warning is somewhat less serious and I'm less clear if I should delete it.)

Comment: I see no reason to delete it; I learned something from the example, and maybe we’ll learn more with your new question, which I’m glad you opened.

Comment: The [method described by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585466/43807) works for me (slightly adapted to have only one savepos): see [lines 191](https://edugit.org/AlekSIS/official/AlekSIS/-/blob/e8729130474bd71723d8410a09bbd72a4f09d646/docs/conf.py#L191), 200–214 and 231f.