# Make tikz rectangle fill whole paperwidth - including margin

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a rectangle that is supposed to cover from the leftmost to the rightmost edge of each page with some centered text in it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[fill=darkgray] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,3cm) node[midway] 
     {\color{lightgray}{\huge{Animals}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However the result is not what I expect:

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you modify your code to make it compilable? i.e. with `\documentclass` etc.

Comment: Here is for one page `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,fill=darkgray,minimum width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm,text=white] (box){\Huge\bfseries Animals};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon if the answer meets your requirement please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon if the answer meets your requirement please accept by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This should help you

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) node[below right,fill=darkgray,minimum 
width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm] (box){};

\path (box.west) node[right=5mm,align=left] %<distance can be changed to suit
{{\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{white}\textbf{JS Bibra}}\\[2mm]
{\fontsize{30pt}{20pt}\color{cyan}Advisor to TEX}\\[2mm]
{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\color{white}\LaTeX\ development}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

For centered text change the `5mm` to any other distance from the left edge of the page for example `10cm`

```
\path (box.west) node[right=10cm,align=left]
```

This would give the following text alignment

[image]

### EDIT2

The difference lies in the addition of the option

```
[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
```

at the beginning of the tikzpicture

After adding the above option to the code of OP the box falls in place

[image]

### MWE of the OP after amending option at the begining

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
\draw (current page.north west) node[below right,fill=darkgray,minimum 
width=\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm] (box){\color{green}{dxczcd}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be working! What if I also want to center the text?

Comment: `\path (box.west) node[right=5mm,align=left] ` -- is specifying the distance from left side of the page-- presently set at `5mm` from left of page-- you can alter 5mm to 10cm depending on the width of the page or column -- for A4 paper the width is `21.0 x 29.7cm`

Answer (score 1):

try \noindent before \begin{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 1):

`tcolorbox` could be another option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, spread sidewards, halign=center, valign=center, sharp corners, colframe=darkgray, colback=darkgray, colupper=lightgray, fontupper=\huge\sffamily, height=3cm ]
Animals
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]