# How to set margin format with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add lines below the name, school and teacher, as shown in the image below, in such a way that even changing the formatting of the margins with the geometry package, the layout below does not change, stay fixed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north) 
   node[below=0.7cm,
        draw=black,
        fill=white,
        minimum width=0.95\paperwidth,
        minimum height=4cm, 
        rounded corners=15pt, 
        line width=3pt]   
                (box){};

\path (box.west) 
      node[right=1mm, align=left] %<distance can be changed to suit
 {{\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{black}\textbf{Name:}}\\[5mm]
 {\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{black}\textbf{School:}}\\[5mm]
 {\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{black}\textbf{Teacher:}}};

% draw rectangle node
\path (current page.center) 
 node[draw,
      minimum width=0.98\paperwidth,
      minimum height=0.97\paperheight, 
        rounded corners=15pt, 
        line width=3pt] (box) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to use this code in a package that I am creating, so I would not like to depend on any external package. If possible, of course!

Comment: If you change margins with `geometry` and text block is smaller than your "external" rectangle, your design won't work. If you want to keep fixed dimensions, it's better not to allow changes with geometry. But if you want a result proportional to text block or page dimensions, it's better that you use "logical" references for your design. Take a look at `tikzpagenodes` packages for that.

Comment: @fsbmat what you look for is relative positioning -- the answer below uses the syntax `current page.north west` and is independent of geometry -- off course there are ways of externally feeding geometry to the code `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`  but that is an answer for a rainy day -- my original answer -  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527919/197451

Comment: @jsbibra in fact, your answer helped me a lot, but I still haven't been able to fully resolve it. I still need to add the lines below the Name, School and Teacher, in order to also maintain the pattern even with changes in spacing and margins! I made changes to the question code.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,remember picture,overlay]
        \path (current page.north west) node[
            below right,
            fill=darkgray,
            minimum width=\paperwidth,
            minimum height=3cm, 
            rounded corners=15pt, 
            line width=3pt
            ]   
                (box){};
        
        \path (box.west) node[
            right=5mm,
            align=left
            ] %<distance can be changed to suit
            {{\fontsize{45pt}{65pt}\color{white}\textbf{JS Bibra}}\\[2mm]
            {\fontsize{30pt}{20pt}\color{cyan}Advisor to TEX}\\[2mm]
            {\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\color{white}\LaTeX\ development}};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```