# Color the toc using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

So, I'm trying to recreate the following style of TOC.

[image]

I used the following:

```
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\draw [fill,red!20] (current page.north west) rectangle
 +(0.33\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\tableofcontents}
```

which I found in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/fill-the-left-1-3-of-the-title-page-with-color). It works OK, but I get only the one page of the TOC filled with color. The second and final page of the TOC is left intact. So, how can I succeed in getting the rectangle produced by tikz to match the two pages of my toc?

Here, is an MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    {\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
        \draw [fill,red!20] (current page.north west) rectangle
        +(0.20\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
        \tableofcontents}
    
    \chapter*{Πρόλογος}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Αντί Προλόγου}
    
    \chapter*{Οδηγός Μελέτης}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Οδηγός Μελέτης}
    
    \part{ΑΛΓΕΒΡΑ}
    
    \chapter{Αλγεβρικές Παραστάσεις}
    
    \section{Πραγματικοί αριθμοί και πράξεις}
    
    \section{Δυνάμεις πραγματικών αριθμών}
    
    \section{Τετραγωνική ρίζα πραγματικού αριθμού}
    
    \section{Μονώνυμα $\bullet$ Πολυώνυμα}
    
    \chapter{Ταυτότητες $-$ Παραγοντοποίηση}
    
    \section{Αξιοσημείωτες ταυτότητες}
    
    \section{Παραγοντοποίηση}
    
    \section{Ε.Κ.Π $\bullet$ Μ.Κ.Δ αλγεβρικών παραστάσεων}
    
    \section{Ρητές αλγεβρικές παραστάσεις}
    
    \section{Πρόσθεση $\bullet$ Αφαίρεση ρητών παραστάσεων}
    
    \chapter{Εξισώσεις - Ανισώσεις}
    
    \section{Η εξίσωση $\alpha x + \beta = 0 $}
    
    \section{Εξίσωση δευτέρου βαθμού}
    
    \section{Επίλυση εξίσωσης δεύτερου βαθμού με τύπο}
    
    \section{Κλασματικές εξισώσεις}
    
    \section{Διάταξη}
    
    \chapter{Συστήματα γραμμικών εξισώσεων}
    
    \section{Η έννοια της γραμμικής εξίσωσης}
    
    \section{Γραμμικό σύστημα}
    
    \part{ΓΕΩΜΕΤΡΙΑ $-$ ΤΡΙΓΩΝΟΜΕΤΡΙΑ}
    
    \chapter{Γεωμετρία}
    
    \section{Πρωτεύοντα - Δευτερεύοντα στοιχεία τριγώνου}
    
    \section{Ίσα τρίγωνα}
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want people to help you need to provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Sure, hold on!!

Comment: @daleif I think the MWE added demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Unrelated: what is up with `ΓΕΩΜΕΤΡΙΑ $-$ ΤΡΙΓΩΝΟΜΕΤΡΙΑ`? the `$-$` part? Doesn't get have access to `--`?

Comment: I just ported it from an older .tex file I had ages ago.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most effecient method, but it does work with my TeXLive 2023 and the hook mechanisms

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{tikz}

\cftinsertcode{pre-toc}{
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}[toc-bg]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw [fill,red!20] (current page.north west) rectangle
    +(0.20\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
  }
}

\cftinsertcode{post-toc}{
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{
    \RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}[toc-bg]
  }
}

% add a hookline into the toc file it self
\AddToHook{begindocument}{
  \cftinserthook{toc}{pre-toc}
}
% add one at the very end as well, we cannot use \cftinserthook there
% as it needs to be immediate
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{enddocument/afterlastpage}{
  \immediate@protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\@writefile{toc}{\string\cftinsert\string{post-toc\string}}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

... % the rest of the OPs example
```

Comment: I run TeXlive 2017 and unfortunately hooks do not work for me!

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: @Tolaso sorry but I see no reason to support such an old LaTeX, upgrade your LaTeX or switch to using overleaf.com